# Wrap LWC OSS App for Mobile

Tags: lightning-web-components, mobilesdk, ios, salesforce-sdk-android, lwc-oss

Is there a way to make an LWC "OSS" app obviously running on Node.js as a Mobile application?  (i.e. Cordova).

I see you can create an LWC Hybrid app running your "Salesforce" LWC components using the Mobile SDK, but this is not the OSS (open source) version of LWC

The use case is to have an application built using LWC OSS + MongoDB/Realm, which we would like to have the LWC app+Node+Realm SDK running as a Hybrid mobile app on both iOS and Android.

Comment: You can create LWC OSS PWA app, does that suits your use case. It wouldn't be hybrid?

Answer (score 1):

The LWC OSS Scaffolding or Project Builder has a PWA (Progressive web app) option. This option allows you to build a "regular web app" which can be "downloaded" to users devices as if they were native to the device. So, you can skip the overall SDK and focus on building an app that will be supported on any device. For more on Progressive web apps:

- [PWA's](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/)
- [How to Build Progressive Web Apps with Offline Support using Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/04/how-to-pwa-offline-lwc.html)

one of the link's above is a blog for adding online support, however, it gives you a good understanding on how to get setup for a PWA LWC OSS app.

fyi: overall, mobile apps and web app development has been shifting towards PWA's in the past years, so they are becoming more and more common.

some advantages include:

- native device support
- less code to maintain in the long run.
- No need to submit your app for review and avoid delays.

Comment: I was able to quickly get a PWA app up-and-running.  Offline support is the main requirement for a large Product Catalog.  Here are the issues:

Comment: offline support is definitely supported with PWA's

Comment: I got tied up and didn't know I submitted that last incomplete comment lol.  So, the offline capability provided by Workbox is limited to the browsers 5MB storage limit, which we have a min 1GB product catalog (largest wine and spirits distributor in the US) per customer sync requirement.  This is working as a POC using LWC+Realm.io.  I am not seeing the advantage of going PWA LWC OSS in our use case, given its limitation for its main capability -- offline.   Yes, you get mobile/desktop app... Not going to scratch it off the list yet, but researching and open to other options

Comment: PWA's can leverage the indexDB which in return leverage the devices storage capacity, therefore, the 5MB storage limit is not representative of the true storage of a PWA. These are all native browser API's that can be used in Javascript